# C++ generic output operator overload

Tags: c++, generics, overloading, operator-keyword, output

```
class W
{
private:
    long m_val1, m_val2;
public:
    W(long& val1, long& val2):m_val1(val1), m_val2(val2) {}
    template<class T>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& w);
};

class X
{
private:
    long m_val1, m_val2;
public:
    X(const long& val1, long& val2):m_val1(val1), m_val2(val2) {}
    template<class T>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& x);
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj)
{
    os << "m_val1: " << obj.m_val1 << ", m_val2: " << obj.m_val2 << endl;
}
```

It does NOT work. Can anyone point out what do I miss? Thanks.
In addition, this results in "error C2593: 'operation <<' is ambiguous" wherever "cout << "some string";" is used.

Answer (score 2):

You have created an output operator that can be called for *all* types, when it's obvious it should only be able to be used for the `W` and `X` classes. You need to narrow the scope of the output operator function.

Comment: How to limit the scope of a generic function and class templates?

Comment: @KokHowTeh One way would be to create a common base class, and have a non-templated output operator for that base class. Or you simply have two output operators, one for each class.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can deduce the template from the call. So when you call `os << "m_val1: "`, based on your template implementation, it creates

```
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const string& obj)
```

witch already exists. More info about template argument deduction in http://accu.org/index.php/journals/409